# У меня есть картинка. Как написать на Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

У меня есть картинка. Как сделать, чтобы при уменьшении экрана, она не меняла высоту, а ширина при этом обрезалась?

Answer (score 1):

Например (и неважно с применением какого bootstrap), высота не меняется, а по ширине обрезается:

```css
.img-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Центрирование картинки */
.img-wrap img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top:50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="img-wrap">
  <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg" alt="">
</div>
```